# Excel Formula to Concatenate IP Addresses for Hostnames with Multiple IP Address Entries in DNS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ip

I have the ff. tables:

**Table A** - a list of 1000+ computers that don't have a specific piece of software installed

**Table B** - a list of 15000+ host-to-IP address entries from the local DNS obtained using the `Get-WmiObject` PS cmdlet.

We're in the process of investigating why the number of computers generated for *Table A* remain high, and I need to get their IP addresses from *Table B*. I was able get the corresponding IP addresses of the machines in *Table A* from their corresponding DNS entries in *Table B* by using the `VLOOKUP` function. The big hurdle that I have is for those hundreds of machines with two or more IP addresses recorded in DNS, as there many laptops that roam and get associated with different subnets.  ***How would it be possible to concatenate the IP address values of two or more cells into one cell for each machine that has multiple IP addresses associated with it using a formula?***  Is there a way to make the formula intelligent enough to detect multiple-entry hostnames and perform the needed concatenation of their multiple IP addresses, and just get the single IP address values for those with just single-entry hostnames?

For example if a single computer has 3 entries (3 rows) in `Table B` that lists its name `PC1.abc.com` 3 times for its 3 IP addresses of `10.10.10.15`, `192.168.10.11`, and `172.16.25.23`, then that computer's entry (1 row) in `Table A` should have a value under the `IP Address` column which should be equal to the combination of all those 3 IP addresses, separated by commas (`,`) -- `10.10.10.15, 192.168.10.11, 172.16.25.23`. I was hoping to use purely non-macro-enabled Excel for this.

Comment: Should be fairly easy if you have Excel 2016, in earlier versions of Excel you can't concatenate an arbitrary number of strings  together using only formulas but it would be possible using helper columns if you could put a ceiling on the number of IP addresses per machine.

Answer (score 0):

Got help from other Excel afficionados online (some issues held me back me from pasting the urls, although I wanted to).  Anyway they could easily be looked up.  Here are two formulas, both of which worked:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(<TableName>[<HostNameColumnName>]=<LookupCell>,<TableName>[<IPAddressColumnName>],""))
```

or

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(<LookupCell>=<TableName>[<HostnameColumnName>],<TableName>[<IPAddressColumnName>],""))
```

As array-entered formulas, both of the above should be entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. If properly entered, the formula will automatically be enclosed with`{}`.

So if the lookup cell is `A2`, the name of the DNS Table (Table B) in Excel is `Table2`,  the name of the column for the hostnames is `HostName`, and the name of the column for the IP addresses is `IP Address`, then the formula would be:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2=Table2[HostName],Table2[IP Address],""))
```

And, if properly entered into the cell using the **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** combination, the resulting formula would appear on the formula bar as:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A2=Table2[HostName],Table2[IP Address],""))}
```

Thanks to all those who provided these answers.